How to transcribe the audio of a video file in Flutter?
I'm building a Flutter app that allows users to upload a video file and generate a text transcript of the audio. I've implemented the code to pick a video file from the gallery and display it using the video_player package. However, when I try to start the transcription using the speech_to_text package, it starts recording the user's audio input instead of transcribing the audio from the video file.
Here's the relevant code I'm using:
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class VideoTranscriptionApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoTranscriptionAppState createState() => _VideoTranscriptionAppState();
}

class _VideoTranscriptionAppState extends State<VideoTranscriptionApp> {
  VideoPlayerController? _videoPlayerController;
  stt.SpeechToText _speechToText = stt.SpeechToText();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _transcriptionData = [];

  void _initializeSpeechToText() {
    _speechToText.initialize();
  }

  Future<void> _pickVideoAndTranscribe() async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickVideo(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      final videoFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(videoFile)
        ..initialize().then((_) {
          setState(() {});
          _startTranscription();
        });
    }
  }

  void _startTranscription() async {
    if (await _speechToText.isAvailable) {
      _speechToText.listen(
        onResult: (result) {
          final word = result.recognizedWords;
          final start = result.alternates.first.recognizedWords;
          final end = result.alternates.last.recognizedWords;
          _transcriptionData.add({
            'word': word,
            'start': start,
            'end': end,
          });
          setState(() {});
        },
      );
    }
  }

  void _stopTranscription() {
    _speechToText.stop();
  }

  // Rest of the code...
}

The issue I'm facing is that the speech_to_text package is transcribing the user's audio input instead of the audio from the video file. How can I modify the code to transcribe the audio from the video file?

What part of this code did you think tried to connect the video to the transcriber?

@ScottHunter this did not. I've been browsing and i haven't found any resources to do this. i just am seeking for any guidance.

I would suggest abandoning your current Flutter/TTS library approach and instead attack the problem in 2 stages.

Extract the audio from the video file using ffmpeg/ffmpeg-kit
Leverage something like OpenAI's Whisper to extract the text from the audio file

